# Signal and Wait in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the below application there are two parties that are calling ChannelReservationCache to fetch or add information.

I want to use the "signal and wait" thing in my ChannelReservationCache class so that in case ChannelReservationCache.AddChannelState() is adding the cache, parallelly if the WebApi call hits the ChannelReservationCache.GetChannel() then the GetChannel() should wait for the execution of AddChannelState() and vice-versa.

**How this can be done in ChannelReservationCache class?**

**Will there be any deadlock?**

```cs
    public class ChannelReservationCache
    {
       private readonly IDictionary<int, string> channelStates = new Dictionary<int, string>>();
       private readonly object lockObject = new object();
       private static readonly object lock = new object();
       private static ChannelReservationCache instance = null;
       
       private ChannelReservationCache() {} 
       
       public static ChannelReservationCache Instance 
       {  
            get 
            {  
                lock(lock) {  
                    if (instance == null) {  
                        instance = new ChannelReservationCache();  
                    }  
                    return instance;  
                }  
            }  
        }
       
       public void AddChannelState(int level, string channel)
       {
          lock (this.lockObject)
          {
              //other code that makes the function take long time.

              this.AddChannel(level, channel);
          }
       }
       
       public Channel GetChannel(int level)
       {
          //other code that makes the function take long time.
          
          Channel c = new Channel()
          channelStates.TryGetValue(destinationId, out var c);
          
          return c;
       }
       
       private void AddChannel(int level, string channel)
       {
          Channel c = new Channel();
          c.ChannelName = channel;
          c.IsActive = true;
          channelStates.Add(level, resourceState)
       }
    }

    public class Channel
    {
      public string ChannelName {get; set;}
      public bool IsActive {get; set;}
    }


    public class RMQRequestHandler
    {
        public Task HandleChannelRequest(int level, Channel messages)
        { 
            ChannelReservationCache.Instance.AddChannelState(level, messages)
        }
    }

    [Route("api/v1")]
    public class ChannnelController: ControllerBase
    {
         [HttpGet]
         [Route("ChannelResource")]
         public IActionResult GetChannelResource([FromQuery] int id)
         {
             ChannelReservationCache crc = ChannelReservationCache.Instance.GetChannel(id);
             return this.Ok(crc);
         }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you update or clear the cache. If it truly is a one-shot deal, you can use `Lazy<T>`, which is guaranteed to execute only once. Doesn't work as well if the cache is going to change continually.

Comment: Consider that there will be multiple calls happening through RMQ and WebApi. For clear and update the cache I haven't added the code here to keep it short.

Comment: GetChannel() is missing the required `lock(this.lockObject)` statement to achieve mutual exclusion.

Comment: As a side note, there is a static [`Channel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel) class in the `System.Threading.Channels` namespace, that can be confused with your custom `Channel` class. Just something to have in mind. :-)

Comment: This is just a replication of the actual code. The class name is different and cannot be posted on this forum.

Comment: @HansPassant : Do you mean adding lock(this.lockObject) to the GetChannel() will serve the purpose. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First off there is a far simpler solution for you:
Simply change

```
private readonly IDictionary<int, string> channelStates = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

To:

```
private readonly IDictionary<int, string> channelStates = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
//using ConcurrentDictionary instead of Dictionary
```

And forget about the thread concurrency locking etc...
In reality it is pretty hard to beat the performance of ConcurrentDictionary by writing our own locking structures to wrap a normal Dictionary. It is possible using ReaderWriterLockSlim to lock the dictionary and Interlocked to maintain a custom implementation for its count property. But this is a micro optimization that would only pay out over millions of itterations.

Now to answer your question:

One issue here:

1. AddChannelState is threadsafe but GetChannel is not
   Think of it this way. Your writer is using a threadsafe lock but your reader is not. GetChannel also needs a lock in it.

Suggestion

2. If you are Not using Lazy < T > in your singleton then it is probably best to make the following change

Code Example below where the cost of thread synchronization is avoided after it has been initialized. Bearing in mind that Lock (or Monitor.Enter / Exit) is one of the most expensive operations to perform. Sure there will be minimum locking contentions once it is initialized however the memory barrier is enforced each and every time plus the Monitor is being checked.

Following reference link is discussing Interlocked but the context of the memory barrier cost is the same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/october/understanding-low-lock-techniques-in-multithreaded-apps

```
private static ChannelReservationCache instance;
private static readonly object lockInstance = new object();
//lock (lockInstance) enforces a memory barrier plus the monitor which is a cost you do not need to bear once the instance has been initialized
public static ChannelReservationCache Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock (lockInstance)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ChannelReservationCache();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: While I can agree with idea, I don't fully support the implementation. Try avoid using concurrent dictionary via interface - see the [thread safety section of docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-6.0#thread-safety) - _"All public and protected members of `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads. However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the dictionary  implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe..."_

Comment: And some of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` methods are implemented explicitly (`Add`, `Remove` and some of derived from parent interfaces).